# How to declare correct function overloading in Typescript while having a callback parameter?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I am trying to rewrite a library that uses pure Javascript to Typescript. More specifically [on this PR](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/pull/1109). I was wondering on how I would able to reproduce the exact function overload defined by their current Typescript types definition (via `@types/X` package) for this specific function:

```js
akeBucket(bucketName: string, region?: string, makeOpts?: MakeBucketOptions, callback?: (err?: Error) => void): void
```

Which have an overload of:

```js
makeBucket(bucketName: string, callback: (err?: Error) => void): void
makeBucket(bucketName: string, region: string, callback?: (err?: Error) => void): void
makeBucket(bucketName: string, region: string, makeOpts: MakeBucketOptions, callback: (err?: Error) => void): void
makeBucket(bucketName: string, region?: string, makeOpts?: MakeBucketOptions, callback?: (err?: Error) => void): void
```

As you can see, the function is callback-styled one for the sake of maintaining backward compatibility with previous version of the library. It also has the `Promise` counterpart of:

```js
makeBucket(bucketName: string): Promise<void>
makeBucket(bucketName: string, region?: string): Promise<void>
makeBucket(bucketName: string, region?: string, makeOpts?: MakeBucketOptions): Promise<void>
```

The `Promise` counterpart is done by modifying the class' prototype with a `promisify` function (see [util/promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal)).

### Current problem

The problem I keep having with the current overload above is a Typescript compiler error that says:

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature. ts(2394)
```

With a code of:

```js
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, callback: (err?: Error) => void): void
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, region: string, callback: (err?: Error) => void): void 
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, region: string, makeOpts: MakeBucketOptions, callback: (err?: Error) => void): void
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, region?: string, makeOpts?: MakeBucketOptions, callback?: (err?: Error) => void): void {
    // implementation
  }
```

From what I understand, Typescript allows us to create a function overload like this (as it doesn't emit any errors from the compiler):

```js
  makeBucket(bucketName: string): void
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, region: string): void 
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, region: string, makeOpts: MakeBucketOptions): void
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, region?: string, makeOpts?: MakeBucketOptions): void {
    // implementation
  }
```

But sadly, that is not what I wanted, as I want to keep the library to be backward compatible, so there should be the `callback?: (err: Error) => void` parameter at the end.

Probable solution might be to have:

```js
type RegionOrOptionsOrCallback = string | MakeBucketOptions | (err?: Error) => void

class Client {
  makeBucket(bucketName: string, ...options?: RegionOrOptionsOrCallback[]): void {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

But that way, users of the library might lose their intellisense on the function parameter name and wouldn't benefit from the Typescript rewrite.

### Question

Is there any way I can make the function overload to be backward compatible without losing the benefit of intellisense (for the users) and optionally able to provide the `Promise` counterpart without having to modify the function (or class method in this case) via the class prototype?

Comment: The class method implementation is not expecting the argument after `bucketName` to be a callback ever.  You need to fix that if you want it to compile, so you can't do it "without having to modify the function".  Such a change might be as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXvnOm) (I ignored your `Promise` counterpart part which seems like a followup question and therefore should probably be removed from here so the post is focused on a single clear question).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it adresses the question.